# What is difference between MessageProducer created using xa session and session?

Tags: java, jms

**What is difference between MessageProducer created  using xasession and session??**

Comment: This is for connection factory i want diff betn producers

Answer (score 0):

If you're in an EE app server, the producer will always be XA.  If you're in SE, you can manually switch to XA.  The XA versions are transactional, so they are meant to operate with an JTA transaction.